# Is it possible to use steam wallpaper in ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04

Just saw this nice zombie wallpaper http://9gag.com/gag/a1bepwb and it's source https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=845108672 is it possible to use it in linux? FYI: I'm very handy with the terminal :)

Comment: Of course you can, either download the image or just right click in Firefox and `set as wallpaper`.

Comment: it's sort of a live wallpaper

Comment: It's not supported for linux http://store.steampowered.com/app/431960/